# Inkscape gives errors when I switch to WebStorm

Tags: 14.04, graphics, ide, inkscape

Every time I try to switch from Inkscape to WebStorm (whether <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or clicking from sidebar) Inkscape keeps giving these error repeatedly:

```
Inkscape has received additional data from the script executed.  The 
script did not return an error, but this may indicate the results will 
not be as expected.
---------------------------------------------------------------------
You need to install the UniConvertor software.
For GNU/Linux: install the package python-uniconvertor.
For Windows: download it from
http://sk1project.org/modules.php?name=Products&product=uniconvertor
and install into your Inkscape's Python location
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I could not figure out why it happens. It happens only between Inkscape and Webstorm. Other applications don't cause this problem.

Any idea why could it be happening?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me ..

```
sudo apt-get update
```

- *Just in case*

then installed this :

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-software-properties
```

And voilá .. until now .. no more issues .. hope it helps more peeps ..

Comment: I will comment again if the same error occurs again but it seems like working for now. Thank you very much!

Comment: The problem is same again.

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.